# document.execCommand('copy') on objects not in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

I'm not 100% sure how to describe this, so I will simply paste three pieces of relevant code.

I am able to do this:

```
var dl = $('<a>',{
    style: 'display: none',
    download: this.name + '.txt',
    href: window.URL.createObjectURL(data, {type: "octet/stream"}))
});
dl[0].click();
```

and I am able to do this:

```
copydeck = $("<textarea>").val(this.list.join("\r\n"));
$('body').append(copydeck);
copydeck.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
copydeck.remove();
```

But I cannot do this:

```
copydeck = $("<textarea>").val(this.list.join("\r\n"));
copydeck[0].select();
document.execCommand('copy');
```

Why? What am I missing here? Am I unable to select or copy elements not in the DOM? Is there a way to do this without appending the object to the body?

Comment: `document`.execCommand('copy') should be implicit.

Comment: My guess is that you can't `copy` from elements that don't exist in the DOM yet.

Comment: `copydeck[0].remove();` - As you never appended the element anywhere, there's nowhere to remove it from. And except on very modern browsers, you don't want that `[0]`. You'd want jQuery's `remove`, not the DOM's. But only if you'd ever actually put it in the DOM.

Comment: Removing isn't the issue here. It's copying the copydeck textarea.

Comment: @Hacketo What do you mean by "should be implicit"?

Comment: @Thirk: I didn't say it was. I was trying to helpfully point out *other* issues. Remember, people are helping here on their own time, for free. Courtesy rather than prickliness goes a long way.

Comment: I'm not using that line in my code - I just duplicated the code above it and made the small change. You're right, I wouldn't need that if I wasn't appending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why? What am I missing here?

The `textarea` isn't in the `document`, so calling `document.execCommand('copy')` won't operate on it. Remember that there can be multiple documents (related to various windows, such as iframes), and until or unless an element is in a document, it...isn't in a document.

You can probably append the `textarea`, issue the command, and then remove it, without causing anything to happen in the display. That said, for me using Chrome on Linux, your code doesn't end up copying anything to the clipboard (whether I start out with the `textarea` in the DOM or add it dynamically later), even if I put it in a `click` handler (e.g., directly responding to a user event).

Comment: The code works using a chrome extension with clipboard permissions, which is what it's for. The block of code in the middle does just as you described.

Why can I click on objects not in the document, but not copy from them?

Comment: @Thirk: Ah, that explains the clipboard thing. So yes, again, if you don't append the element to the document you're calling `execCommand` on, the document doesn't know about it, and can't copy it. So you'll have to append and remove it.

Comment: @Thirk: *"Why can I click on objects not in the document, but not copy from them?"* Because in the click scenario, you're triggering the event on the element itself; in the copy scenario, you're calling a method of `document`, and that document apparently only applies that command to elements actually in its tree.